# How do you install pygame on a (Ubuntu) system with multiple python installs?

Tags: ubuntu, python

On my ubuntu box I have python2.6 and python 3.1 installed. I did some work with pygame / python2.6, and now I want to play with python3.1 / pygame. However, in idle (using python3.1) when I import pygame, I get errors.

```
>>> import pygame
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
import pygame
ImportError: No module named pygame
```

So, what is the proper way to install pygame for multiple python installs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install it multiple times.

```
python2.6 setup.py install
python3.1 setup.py install
```

Comment: hmmm.. Im going to need some additional hand holding I think. Im going to assume setup.py would be in somewhere in a python directory and that Im supposed to get in that directory then run it. Where do I get setup.py? I searched my harddrive for it, and I dont see it (damn enter button posts...) anywhere in there, and I dont see it on the pygame downloads page. Will continue looking.

Comment: `setup.py` comes with the source tarball for the Python module you're installing (Pygame in this instance). http://docs.python.org/install/index.html